# Error 1044 Access denied to user

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.5

This is driving me crazy.

When I try to create a few tables from my Workbench model I get this `error 1044`.

I've been trying to find a solution but nothing works for me.

Curiously when I run `SELECT USER(),CURRENT_USER();` I get two versions of the same user.  One is `techboy@(an ip address)` and the other is `techboy@%`.

Access is denied to both at one point or another.

The MySql server is a remote hosted server with the user permissions correctly set.

Comment: Check if grants are there for table creation.

Answer (score 2):

Please keep in mind that when you run

```
SELECT USER(),CURRENT_USER();
```

[USER()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/information-functions.html#function_user) reports how you attempted to authenticate in mysqld

[CURRENT_USER()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/information-functions.html#function_current-user) reports how you were allowed to authenticate by mysqld

This means you should run this query

```
SHOW GRANTS FOR CURRENT_USER();
```

or just

```
SHOW GRANTS;
```

to actually see your credentials. If you run,

```
SHOW GRANTS FOR USER();
```

you may not see credentials if they do not exist in `mysql.user`.

Just try to make the appropriate user on the MySQL Instance.

## UPDATE 2013-03-05 16:51 EST

In you comment, you said

> Grants shows that 'GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO \'techboy\'@\'%\' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD \'and a character string\'' and 'GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON lfc_123awards.* TO \'techboy\'@\'%\' WITH GRANT OPTION'

Since you only have rights to the `lfc_123awards` database, please make sure you are specifying that database when you connect. If you do not set the default database at authentication, it will not let you connect at all.

Here is what I mean: Let say you trying connecting from the command line

```
mysql -utechbox -p -hIPofDBServer
```

This should fail, whereas

```
mysql -utechbox -p -hIPofDBServer -Dlfc_123awards
```

should work.

Comment: Thanks. Grants shows that 'GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO \'techboy\'@\'%\' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD \'*and a character string\'' and 'GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `lfc_123awards`.* TO \'techboy\'@\'%\' WITH GRANT OPTION'
Where does this leave me? I know I am signed in with the correct credentials.

Comment: Got it to work! Thanks for your help RolandoMySQDBA.